# Fill a shape in Excel based on a percentage value?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to format a shape in excel such that it gets filled based on a percentage value. So if I had a table with percentage values of 25%, 50%, and 75%, I would be able to get a 3 circles filled at those percentage points (similar to a pie chart, but with only one value).
From googling it doesn't seem possible in excel, but wanted to ask anyway to see if there was a workaround. In addition, is there a way to do this in another program by importing the excel file to it?

Comment: have you tried conditional formating ?

Comment: Not sure how to do it with a solid fill instead of gradient

Comment: If it's 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% or 100% there is a preset conditional format that looks like that under: Conditional formatting → Icons... → classification → Fifths. Then you have to select formula for each case and apply a limit for each one like 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 & 0.8

Comment: The Conditional Format - Icons will work _only_ if you want to display increments of quater circles.  If you might have other values, and arn't fixed on circles, you could use Conditional Format - Data Bars

Comment: You can also insert a shape of type "Partial Circle" at set it to whatever percentage you want.  You will have much more control over how it displays than you will with Icons (or Data Bars)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have also tagged this VBA, here's a Sub that will add Pie shapes to a table

```
Sub Demo()
    CreatePies ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1), "Percent", "Pies", RGB(0, 0, 0), 180!, False

End Sub

Sub CreatePies(lo As ListObject, ValueColName As String, PieColumnName As String, Optional Color As Long = 0, Optional StartAt As Single = 0!, Optional CW As Boolean = True)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As ListRow
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim PieCol As Long, PercentCol As Long
    Dim L As Single, T As Single, W As Single, H As Single

    Set ws = lo.Parent

    'Delete Old Pies
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.Name Like "Pie_*" Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next

    PercentCol = lo.ListColumns(ValueColName).Index
    With lo.ListColumns(PieColumnName)
        PieCol = .Index
        L = .DataBodyRange.Left + .DataBodyRange.Width / 2!
    End With

    For Each lr In lo.ListRows
        With lr.Range.Cells(1, PieCol)
            T = .Top
            H = .Height
            W = H
        End With
        Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, L - W / 2!, T, W, H)
        With shp
            .Name = "Pie_" & lr.Index
            .Line.Visible = msoFalse
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color
        End With
        If CW Then
            shp.Adjustments(1) = StartAt
            shp.Adjustments(2) = lr.Range.Cells(1, PercentCol).Value * 360! + StartAt
        Else
            shp.Adjustments(2) = StartAt - 360!
            shp.Adjustments(1) = (1 - lr.Range.Cells(1, PercentCol).Value) * 360! + StartAt
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Sample end result

[image]